# Scale image matrix until a certain width then wrap them

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the effect shown in the image with just HTML and CSS (the example uses JavaScript).

Is it possible at all to scale down the images, then wrap them at a certain width?

[image: scaling and wrapping image matrix]

Here is a Codepen with basic wrapping without the scaling down https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVOVaG

```css
.outerDiv {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 0rem;
  margin-left: 0rem;
}

.innerDiv {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.imageDiv {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/harrypotterandthecursedchild_58482_1_1_20160804105944.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/harrypotterandthecursedchild_58482_1_1_20160804105944.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/harrypotterandthecursedchild_58482_1_1_20160804105944.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/fcbarcelona_431_1_1_20160908181513.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/fcbarcelona_431_1_1_20160908181513.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/bethhart_1880_1_3_20161201140946.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/bethhart_1880_1_3_20161201140946.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the [Bootstrap Grid System](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) ?

Comment: Bootstrap uses JavaScript to achieve that as well. I am looking for a pure CSS + HTML solution.

Comment: Yes, you can set the width of each item to 100% and then add media queries to change the width to 50%, 33.333%, and 25% where you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

.outerDiv {
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.innerDiv {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.imageDiv {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 460px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .innerDiv {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .innerDiv {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .innerDiv {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/harrypotterandthecursedchild_58482_1_1_20160804105944.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/fcbarcelona_431_1_1_20160908181513.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/bethhart_1880_1_3_20161201140946.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/harrypotterandthecursedchild_58482_1_1_20160804105944.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/fcbarcelona_431_1_1_20160908181513.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/bethhart_1880_1_3_20161201140946.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/harrypotterandthecursedchild_58482_1_1_20160804105944.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/fcbarcelona_431_1_1_20160908181513.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/bethhart_1880_1_3_20161201140946.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/harrypotterandthecursedchild_58482_1_1_20160804105944.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/fcbarcelona_431_1_1_20160908181513.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv">
      <img src="http://stwv-s3.global.ssl.fastly.net/filestore/season/image/bethhart_1880_1_3_20161201140946.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to achieve something like this the `img`s need to be wide enough, but it depends on how wide is the *container* in the first place. For better presentation I've set it to be `1200px` wide. Original `302px` wide pictures you provided are not wide enough so I've made them `460px` because of the last *"break"* at `480px` and `10px` `column-gap`. Fell free to adjust everything to your needs.